# How to collapse a Web Push notification sent by FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin, web-push

I'm using FCM with firebase-admin to send a Web Push notification for multiple clients. I want to replace an older message by a new one.

This is how I'm calling it:

```js
return await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
  tokens,
  notification: {
    title: "Message Title",
    body: "Message body.",
  },
  data: {
    type: "ring",
    callId,
  },
  webpush: {
    fcmOptions: {
      link: process.env.PWA_APP_URL,
    },
    headers: {
      Urgency: "high",
    },
  },
  android: {
    collapseKey: "ring",
    priority: "high",
    ttl: 10,
    notification: {
      color: "#ff0000",
      defaultSound: true,
      sound: "default",
      lightSettings: {
        color: "#ffcc00",
        lightOffDurationMillis: 1000,
        lightOnDurationMillis: 1000,
      },
      tag: "ring",
      vibrateTimingsMillis: [1000, 1000],
      visibility: "public",
      priority: "max",
    },
  },
});
```

When the message arrives to an Android app client it's collapsed because of `android.collapseKey` property. But I can't get the same behavior in my web application.

According to the docs, there's a [Topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#which_should_i_use) option for Web notifications, but I'm not sure [where to put it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MulticastMessage). I tried to use it as `webpush.headers.Topic` property but with no success. Messages are not collapsed in Android/Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you call [showNotification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) in your service worker you can pass a `tag` option: any previous notification with that tag is replaced. This is the Push API standard... I don't know how the proprietary FCM SDK handles that options.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed [collimarco's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778236/how-to-collapse-a-web-push-notification-sent-by-fcm?noredirect=1#comment112781178_63778236) and could use [showNotification method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) to collapse a notification.

In firebase-admin/server code I had to remove the notification fields in the message's payload. Now it's just a [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

```js
return await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
  tokens,
  data: {
    type: "ring",
    callId,
  },
});
```

In the web application I created a [background message handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_background). Now I can call `showNotification` method when I new message arrives using `tag` property with `renotify=true`.

```js
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  // ...
  return self.registration.showNotification("Message Title", {
    body: "Message body.",
    tag: "ring",
    renotify: true,
    vibrate: [1000, 1000],
  });
});
```

It would be great to have these properties set on the message payload only.